# How to make a generic function when the target of the type to be parameterized is not a top level property?

Tags: c#, function, generics

More generally I'm wondering how you make a generic routine when the target of the type to be parameterized is not a top level property.

Specifically, I'm working on eliminating the duplication from these two functions:

```
    private static string ExceptionMessage(Exception e)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        Exception exception = e;
        while (exception != null)
        {
            if (e.Message != null)
            {
                if (result.Length > 0)
                {
                    result += Separator;
                }
                result += exception.Message;
            }
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static string Tag(Exception e)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        Exception exception = e;
        while (exception != null)
        {
            if (e.TargetSite != null)
            {
                if (result.Length > 0)
                {
                    result += Separator;
                }
                result += exception.TargetSite.Name;
            }
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way (currently) to do this explicitly via generics, and I take it that sending a Boolean argument to your function isn't what you're looking for.

You can go around this by passing in a closure that extracts the part of the Exception instance you require, like in the example below:

```
private static string AggregateException(Exception e, Func<Exception,string> getPart){
        string result = string.Empty;
        Exception exception = e;
        while (exception != null)
        {
            if (e.Message != null)
            {
                if (result.Length > 0)
                {
                    result += Separator;
                }
                result += getPart(exception);
            }
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        return result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
    string msg = AggregateException(myEx, (ex) => ex.Message);
    string tag = AggregateException(myEx, (ex) => ex.TargetSite.Name);
```